# Why does order of testing change testing results?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, time

I have coded 2 sorting methods (Bubble sort and Merge sort) that I know have different efficiencies so I wanted to graph these out for different array sizes. Just to check that the times were as expected, I did a test run where I generated a 10000 random values and put them in an array, did a bubble sort on it, then generated them again and did an merge sort. I timed both. But when I looked at the time it took for bubble sort, it was far, far less than on the merge sort. So I switched which one I did first and now the merge sort was fastest. Why does this happen and how can I stop it?
Here's all of my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Sorter {
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isInOrder(ArrayList<T> ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (ar.get(i).compareTo(ar.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isInOrder(T[] ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length - 1; i++) {
        if (ar[i].compareTo(ar[i + 1]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static <T> ArrayList<T> splitArrayList(ArrayList<T> ar, int start, int end) {
    ArrayList<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        toReturn.add(ar.get(i));
    }
    return toReturn;
}

private static <T extends Comparable> ArrayList<T> merge(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b) {
    ArrayList<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    int bIndex = 0;
    for (T value : a) {
        while (bIndex < b.size() && (b.get(bIndex).compareTo(value) < 0)) {
            toReturn.add(b.get(bIndex));
            bIndex++;
        }
        toReturn.add(value);
    }
    if (bIndex <= b.size()) {
        for (int i = bIndex; i < b.size(); i++) {
            toReturn.add(b.get(i));
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public static <T extends Comparable> ArrayList<T> mergeSort(ArrayList<T> ar) {
    if (ar.size() == 1) return ar;
    else {
        int splitPoint = ar.size() / 2;
        ArrayList<T> split1 = mergeSort(splitArrayList(ar, 0, ar.size() / 2));
        ArrayList<T> split2 = mergeSort(splitArrayList(ar, ar.size() / 2, ar.size()));
        ar = merge(split1, split2);
    }
    return ar;
}


public static <T extends Comparable> ArrayList<T> bubbleSort(ArrayList<T> ar) {
    boolean isSorted = false;
    while (!isSorted) {
        isSorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (ar.get(i).compareTo(ar.get(i + 1)) > 1) {
                T holdValue = ar.get(i);
                ar.set(i, ar.get(i + 1));
                ar.set(i + 1, holdValue);
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return ar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> test = generateRandomData(100000);
    double t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mergeSort(test);
    double t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    test = generateRandomData(100000);
    double t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    bubbleSort(test);
    double t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Merge sort " + (t2-t1) + " Bubble Sort "  + (t4-t3));
}
public static ArrayList<Double> generateRandomData(int size){
    ArrayList<Double> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        toReturn.add(Math.random());
    }
    return toReturn;
}
}
```

Comment: You're not actually sorting the arrays. Adding a check after each test for `isInOrder` returns `false` for both your bubble and merge sort. I checked it works by sorting some test data with `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this looks odd is because your BubbleSort is not actually sorting the arrays. With your code, given an array `[6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]`, after running the method we wind up with: `[6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]`. Hmmm. That looks a lot like what we started with.

The error is simple. In the line

```
if (ar.get(i).compareTo(ar.get(i + 1)) > 1) {
```

The `compareTo` method returns one of `-1`, `0`, `1`, depending on whether or not the argument is less than, equal to, or greater than, respectively. Change it to

```
if (ar.get(i).compareTo(ar.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
```

And it will work correctly (and go very, very slowly).

As your MergeSort works correctly, you should see a much different picture between BubbleSort and MergeSort.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the JVM getting warmed up. Try running each sorter a few times and then time the over 10 runs each and average the times.

It could be a coincidence in the generation of the random data. Multiple runs will help clear that up.

Comment: The faster one is whichever comes first. How does that fit in with "getting warmed up"?

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to the garbage collection overhead you are paying when you are discarding those first set of 100,000 randomly generated `Double` objects.

You could verify this hypothesis by separating the test data collections and preventing them from being garbage collected until both sort algorithms are finished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> test1 = generateRandomData(100000);
    double t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mergeSort(test1);
    double t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ArrayList<Double> test2 = generateRandomData(100000);
    double t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    bubbleSort(test2);
    double t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Merge sort " + (t2-t1) + " Bubble Sort "  + (t4-t3));
}
```

Comment: @rcgldr or generate one set and use it twice

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, the merge sort is probably impacted by using toReturn.add(). Create a merge sort entry function that does a one time allocation of a temp array, then that function should call the actual merge sort function and pass the temp array as a parameter, and the merge sort function also pass the temp array as a parameter to the merge function. Other than the entry function, the functions would not allocate any arrays, just index the arrays to do compares and moves.

You can also eliminate the copy to / back steps by using a pair of mutually recursive functions. The entry recursive function calls the other recursive function to merge sort into the temp array, then merges the runs from the temp array to the original array. The other function merges sorts from temp array to the original array, then merges the runs from the original array to the temp array. For the other function, if the run size is 1, then it copies one element from the original array to the temp array. For the entry recursive function, if run size is 1, then it just returns since it's supposed to end up with sorted runs in the original array.

For most languages, bottom up merge sort would be slightly faster, but for Java it doesn't seem to help. Also in merge(), the copy rest of run loops should be faster using do .... while, but with Java it's slightly faster using while, even though there's always at least one loop done. Since Java generics are handled at run time, it creates an overhead compared to C++ templates which are handled at compile time (creating multiple instances of code based on parameter type(s)).

Example top down merge sort converted from a C program (I'm not that familiar with Java). It doesn't use generic types. I had to increase the array size to 1 million in order to avoid the time showing up as 0. On my system, Win 7 Pro 64 bit, Intel 2600K 3.4 ghz, it takes about 125 ms (64hz ticker so time is +/- 15.625 ms) to sort 1 million doubles. 10 million doubles takes around 1.2 seconds.

```
package jsorttd;
import java.util.Random;

public class jsorttd {

    static void MergeSort(double a[]) {
        if (a.length < 2)
            return;
        double []b = new double[a.length];
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, 0, a.length);
    }

    static void MergeSortAtoA(double a[], double b[], int ll, int ee)
    {
        if (ee - ll > 1) {
            int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          // midpoint, start of right half
            MergeSortAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
            MergeSortAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
            Merge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);        // merge b to a
        }
    }

    static void MergeSortAtoB(double a[], double b[], int ll, int ee)
    {
        if (ee - ll > 1) {
            int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          //midpoint, start of right half
            MergeSortAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
            MergeSortAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
            Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);        // merge a to b
        } else if ((ee - ll) == 1) {
            b[ll] = a[ll];
        }
    }

    static void Merge(double []a, double []b, int ll, int rr, int ee) {
        int o = ll;                         // b[]       index
        int l = ll;                         // a[] left  index
        int r = rr;                         // a[] right index
        while(true){                        // merge data
            if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
                b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
                if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(r < ee){              //   else copy rest of right run
                    b[o++] = a[r++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
                b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
                if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(l < rr){              //   else copy rest of left run
                    b[o++] = a[l++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double []a = new double[1000000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = r.nextDouble();
        long bgn, end;
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort(a);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
                System.out.println("failed");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("milliseconds " + (end-bgn));
     }
}
```